# In how many ways can 12 students be seated in a classroom that has 30 seats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm a bit confused on this question. Normally, if there were $n$ students and $m$ seats such that $n > m$, it would be a simple application of $n * n-1 * \dots$, $m$ times. Since the # of seats is greater than the # of students, I *think* the answer is

$12! * \binom{30}{12}$

but I am not sure if this makes sense. You have $12!$ possible ways of arranging the students and $\binom{30}{12}$ ways of choosing $12$ seats from $30$ seats. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You can think of it as $30*29*28*...*19$ which indeed matches your proposed solution.  (First student has 30 seats to choose from...)

Comment: Wow, that was my original solution and I didn't even realize they are the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  ${30\choose{12}}*12!=\frac{30!}{12!18!}*12!=\frac{30!}{18!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Out of $30$ seats, we need to choose $12$, so ${30 \choose 12}$ gives us that number.

Now we have $12$ locations. In the first seat we have $12$ potential students, in the second we have $11$, in the third we have $10$, and so on. That gives us $12!$ ways of arranging $12$ students in $12$ seats.

Multiplying the number of possible seats with the number of combinations of students in those seats, we get the result: $12!\cdot{30 \choose 12}$.

Answer (score 1):

That there are more seats then students doesn't matter.

30 choices for the first student, 29 for the second and so on.  $\frac {30!}{18!}$ total.

If there were n students > m chairs then there'd be $\frac {m!}{n-m!}$ with n - m students unseated.  If n students < m chairs there are $\frac {m!}{m -n}$ with m - n seats unfilled.

It's no different.